# Persistent dynamic control in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, controls, persistent

```
<asp:Button onclick="Some_event" Text="Add TextBox" ID="id1" runat="server" />
//once clicked:
<asp:TextBox ID="txt1" ......></asp:TextBox>
//when clicked again:
<asp:TextBox ID="txt1" ......></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txt2" ......></asp:TextBox>
//and so on...
```

Is there a way to create dynamic controls which will persist even after the postback? In other words, when the user clicks on the button, a new textbox will be generated and when clicks again the first one will remain while a second one will be generated. How can I do this using asp.net ? I know that if I can create the controls in the page_init event then they will persist but I dont know if it possible to handle a button click before the page_init occurs, therefore there must be another way.

Comment: The controls *must* be re-created on postback. However, there are some projects to make this task automated, such as [DynamicControlPlaceholder](http://www.denisbauer.com/ASPNETControls/DynamicControlsPlaceholder.aspx) (it persists and later re-creates the controls).

Comment: yes I've read about it but I'd like to learn this stuff :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. One way to do this using purely ASP.NET (which seems like what you're asking for) would be to keep a count of the `TextBox` controls that you have added (storing that value in the `ViewState`) and recreate the `TextBox` controls in the `Page_Load` event. Of course, nowadays most people would probably use Javascript or jQuery to handle this task client side, but I put together a quick example to demonstrate how it works with postbacks:

Front page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="DynamicControls.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyAspnetApp.DynamicControls" EnableViewState="true" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server"></head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="btnAddTextBox" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="btnAddTextBox_Click" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnWriteValues" runat="server" Text="Write" OnClick="btnWriteValues_Click" />
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phControls" runat="server" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace MyAspnetApp
{
    public partial class DynamicControls : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Recreate textbox controls
            if(Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < TextBoxCount; i++)
                    AddTextBox(i);
            }
        }

        private int TextBoxCount
        {
            get 
            {
                var count = ViewState["txtBoxCount"];
                return (count == null) ? 0 : (int) count;
            }
            set { ViewState["txtBoxCount"] = value; }
        }

        private void AddTextBox(int index)
        {
            var txt = new TextBox {ID = string.Concat("txtDynamic", index)};
            txt.Style.Add("display", "block");
            phControls.Controls.Add(txt);
        }

        protected void btnAddTextBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AddTextBox(TextBoxCount);
            TextBoxCount++;
        }

        protected void btnWriteValues_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach(var control in phControls.Controls)
            {
                var textBox = control as TextBox;
                if (textBox == null) continue;
                Response.Write(string.Concat(textBox.Text, "<br />"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Since you are recreating the controls on each postback, the values entered into the textboxes will be persisted across each postback. I added `btnWriteValues_Click` to quickly demonstrate how to read the values out of the textboxes.

**EDIT**
I updated the example to add a Panel containing a TextBox and a Remove Button. The trick here is that the Remove button does not delete the container Panel, it merely makes it not Visible. This is done so that all of the control IDs remain the same, so the data entered stays with each TextBox. If we were to remove the TextBox entirely, the data after the TextBox that was removed would shift down one TextBox on the next postback (just to explain this a little more clearly, if we have txt1, txt2 and txt3, and we remove txt2, on the next postback we'll create two textboxes, txt1 and txt2, and the value that was in txt3 would be lost).

```
public partial class DynamicControls : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < TextBoxCount; i++)
                AddTextBox(i);
        }
    }

    protected void btnAddTextBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddTextBox(TextBoxCount);
        TextBoxCount++;
    }

    protected void btnWriteValues_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(var control in phControls.Controls)
        {
            var panel = control as Panel;
            if (panel == null || !panel.Visible) continue;
            foreach (var control2 in panel.Controls)
            {
                var textBox = control2 as TextBox;
                if (textBox == null) continue;
                Response.Write(string.Concat(textBox.Text, "<br />"));
            }
        }
    }

    private int TextBoxCount
    {
        get 
        {
            var count = ViewState["txtBoxCount"];
            return (count == null) ? 0 : (int) count;
        }
        set { ViewState["txtBoxCount"] = value; }
    }

    private void AddTextBox(int index)
    {
        var panel = new Panel();
        panel.Controls.Add(new TextBox {ID = string.Concat("txtDynamic", index)});
        var btn = new Button { Text="Remove" };
        btn.Click += btnRemove_Click;
        panel.Controls.Add(btn);
        phControls.Controls.Add(panel);
    }

    private void btnRemove_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var btnRemove = sender as Button;
        if (btnRemove == null) return;
        btnRemove.Parent.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What about if I want to delete the dynamic textbox? I insert a button and assign an event to it whenever a textbox is created. Actually, on the first click the textbox is being deleted succesfully, but then some errors may occur (not exceptions but for instance the value of the textbook is not saved on click). Is there an easy way to delete the specified textbox?

Comment: @Shaokan I updated my answer to include deleting of the TextBoxes as well.

Comment: haha it was so easy :) I was keeping to remove the panel, thanks alot again :) it works fully now :)

Answer (score 1):

I read an article by Scott Mitchell that explains that ViewState only persists changed control state across post-back, and not the actual controls themselves. I did not have your exact scenario, but a project I was working on required dynamically added user controls and I had to add them on every postback. In that case, it is still useful to create them in Init so that they can retain their state. Here is the link: [Understanding ASP.NET View State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx#viewstate_topic4). Check section “View State and Dynamically Added Controls”.

You may have to keep track of all the controls that you are adding (in session state for example) and re-create them on post back. I just did a small test where I keep a `List<string>` of all the Textbox ids in Session. On postback, I recreate all the textboxes.

Comment: thanks a lot! guess I have a lot to read while I'm in vacation :)