# Dynamically create a button in aspx page

Tags: html, asp.net

i want to make some elements in my asp form like below, unfortunately input button dose not work and "btnsave_ServerClick" dose not fire! 
any body has idea?

```
<div class="clear"></div>
<%
    string matn="";
    System.Data.DataTable ds = new System.Data.DataTable();
    try
    {
       // databaselinker is a class which is connected to the database
        databaselinker link = new databaselinker();
       // id is QueryString parameter
        ds = link.selectplan(id);
    }
   catch (Exception Ex) { }
   int i=0;
    foreach (System.Data.DataRow DRow in ds.Rows)
    {

        TableRow tRow = new TableRow();
        matn += "<div class='frame' id='frame" + DRow["PlanID"] + "'>";
        matn += " name <input id='Text1' type='text' /> * ";
        matn += "</br>";
        matn += "Family  <input id='Text2' type='text' /> * ";
        matn += "<input id='Button1' type='button' value='Save'   runat='server' onServerClick='btnsave_ServerClick' />";

        matn += "</div>";
        i++;

    }

    Response.Write(matn);

      %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you type that `button` as `string` on this line

```
matn += "<input id='Button1' type='button' value='Save'   runat='server' onServerClick='btnsave_ServerClick' />";
```

the `asp.net` did not know anything about that button, even if you have place the `runat=` is still a string.

when you have render that string using the

```
Response.Write(matn);
```

asp.net compile the `response.write` but NOT compile the string that you render of.

And that is the reason that is not working and not fire.
To make it work you need to create it dynamically.

Some examples on how to do it:
[HOW TO: Dynamically Create Controls in ASP.NET by Using Visual C# .NET](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/317794)
[Dynamic Controls Made Easy in ASP.Net](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Dynamic-Controls-Made-Easy-in-ASP.Net.aspx)
[Persistent dynamic control in ASP.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797268/persistent-dynamic-control-in-asp-net)

Comment: In this new way that you told, is it possible to create <div> dynamically ? or just controls?

Comment: @zafy Yes you can create and div, you can use a literal, and add the div inside - how ever the dynamic creation of the buttons that way is not always needed... see if you can use a custom control to do the same...